# When does MLE = MAP? With ELI5 example

Tags: machine-learning, maximum-likelihood

Definitions:

- MLE = Maximum likelihood estimation.
- MAP = Maximum Apriori Estimation.

If we were to use a simple example and say "Use MLE to find the number of free throws made out of 10", we would pick 5 as the most probable number of free throws made out of 10.

With the previous example, lets say we received new information that the player is an NBA player. Given that the player is a NBA player, MAP would probably pick 7 as the most probable number of free throws made out of 10.

Now the question is, when is MLE = MAP? And I can only think of one case:

1. When the updated "new" information is irrelevant/does not change the probability in question. So for example, if given we know a player's race, MLE and MAP would both still pick 5 as the most probable estimate.

Is that understanding correct? Please correct the examples as well if there is a problem with the understanding in them.

Comment: A uniform prior will lead to MLE = MAP (i.e. the mode of the likelihood would be equal to the mode of the posterior since that is proportional to the likelihood times the constant prior)

Comment: But I have totally failed to understand your example